# Module not found when using typescript in worker_threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-worker-threads

const worker = new Worker('./counter.js')

my index.ts file

```
import { Worker, isMainThread } from "worker_threads";

if (isMainThread) {
    const worker = new Worker('./counter.js')
    worker.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })

    worker.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

my counter.ts file

```
`import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";

let count = 0;

for(let i=0;i<2000;i++){
    count++
}

parentPort.postMessage(count)
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"node dist/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev":"ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "NodeNext",
      "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
      "target": "ES2020",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
  }
```

require('./counter')
when i tested with ejs and commonjs it works fine but when passing the file name inside Worker()
it shows the error of module not found`your text`